# ASP.NET MVC - Add Query String Value to RedirectToAction in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. My app is using T4MVC. In my controller, I need to redirect from one action to another. When I do this, I want to append a query string value. I can successfully redirect without the query string value, but I've been unsuccessful applying a query string value. My actions look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult Action1()
{                        
   return RedirectToAction(MVC.MyController.Action2().AddRouteValue("id", "5"));
}

[Route("action-2")]
public virtual ActionResult Action2(string input)
{
  ViewBag.Input = input;
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

The `Action2` works fine when I visit `./action-2`. I can also successfully POST to `Action1`. But, when the redirect doesn't work. I notice in the address bar the following:

```
/MyController/id
```

Why? How do I fix this? I just want to redirect back to `Action2` but this time with a query string parameter added. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not just `return RedirectToAction("Action2", "MyController", new { id = 5});`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the parameter by the name in the action (in this case "`input`") in order for it to work, see below:

```
return redirectToAction(MVC.MyController.Action2().AddRouteValue("input", "5"));
```

or alternatively:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action2", "MyController", new { input = "myInput"});
```

Comment: can you kindly check this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75826012/how-to-redirect-to-a-view-from-a-viewcomponent-while-passing-a-value-via-url

Answer (score -1):

I try in following way and it works fine for me.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "CustomBuilder", new { usern = "admin" });
```